# Sharing the host OS or sharing the Container OS

Tags: docker

When running an Ubuntu Docker container on Mac or other OS host, 
is the UBunto OS really running in the container or is it some kind of a virtual interface?

From my understanding containers share the OS, I just need to understand if it is the OS from the host or it really is a operation system within the container?

If a Docker container is some kind of a virtual interface to the host like; Docker Containe:

- http is served from the host
- File and folders is served from the host

Then a Docker Container could run on any host OS as long as the interface is there, right?

Thanks for any input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is from the documentation - I missed it, reading it the first time:

How does a container work?

A container consists of an operating system, user-added files, and meta-data. As we've seen, each container is built from an image. That image tells Docker what the container holds, what process to run when the container is launched, and a variety of other configuration data. The Docker image is read-only. When Docker runs a container from an image, it adds a read-write layer on top of the image (using a union file system as we saw earlier) in which your application can then run.